# Mechanics - Homework

Tags: physics, quadratics

A stone is thrown vertically down from a high building with an initial velocity of $4\;\mathrm ms^{-1}$. Calculate the time required for the stone to travel $30\;\mathrm m$.
So far I have tried using the SUVAT equation $$s = ut + \frac12at$$
Using this:

$$\begin{align}
u &= 4\\
s &= 30\\
a &= 9.8\\
t &= ?\\
30 &= 4t + \frac12(9.8)t\\
30 &= 4t + 4.9t\\
30 &= 8.9t\\
t &= 3.37s\end{align}$$

According to my book that is incorrect, but I'm not sure where I have gone wrong and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You should review whatever SUVAT means: it should be $(1/2)at^2$ not $(1/2)at$.

Comment: ah, thank you so much, completely missed that :D

Comment: @julien, why don't you call that an answer and put this thing to bed?

Comment: @dfeuer Sure, done.

Answer (score 3):

It should be $0.5 at^2$ instead of $0.5at$. Hence a quadratic equation.

Note this comes from the fact that the acceleration $s''$ is equal to $a=9.8$. Then integrated twice.